# Правильно ли говорить или писать "человек совершил происшествие"?

Tags: выбор-слов, семантика

Можно ли сказать "человек совершил происшествие"?

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это неправильно. *Происшествие* - это **то, что произошло** при совокупности каких-либо конкретных условий, при участии людей или без них. Произошедшее может быть *результатом* действия человека, но не *содержанием* этого действия. Поэтому можно некое происшествие спровоцировать, стать его участником, причиной или виновником, но нельзя "совершить". Это понятие *шире*, чем действие, и включает в себя условия и обстоятельства, при которых нечто *произошло*.